# replace nested loops to recurssion

Tags: java

I have a 3 level nested loop. Value of inner ones depend on immediately above ones. The performance is really a killer right now O(n*n*n). Also, there can be certain out.println in the immediate loops too, which needs to be printed. How can I replace with recursion or is there any other way I can avoid nested loops and improve upon performance.

Sample code:

```
String[] strArray = getOuterArray();
for(String x : strArray){
        String[] internalStrArray = x.getArray();
        System.out.println("I am in first");
    for(String x: internalStrArray){
        String[] internalinStrArray = x.getArray();
        System.out.println("I am in second");
        for(String x: internalinStrArray){
            System.out.println("I am in third "+ x);
        }
    }
}

public String[] getOuterArray(){
}

public String[] getArray(){
}
```

Comment: Recursion probably won't improve performance... it might make the code more compact and easier to read but that's a different story.

Comment: Huh?  If you really need to run n^3 times, then it will still be n^3 even if you use recursion.

Comment: Why would recursion change the O(n*n*n)? If anything, it'll just burn through your stack.

Comment: I don't see how your code could take O(n*n*n) to run when it doesn't even compile.  `x` is a `String` and `String` doesn't have a `getArray` method.  I have absolutely no idea what kind of algorithm you are trying to code.  Please post some real code.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is not going to be faster then loops.  In fact, due to pushing a function call onto the stack, it could very well be slower.

Right now your code makes no sense, you are printing out "I am in first/second/third" inside the loop.  You aren't really doing anything arithmetically that can be improved.  The only main suggestion I have is to not name all the variables x, that is very confusing.

As long as you have those three loops and want to do all that printing, nothing can make it go faster.

Comment: "The only main suggestion I have is to not name all the variables x, that is very confusing" ... it also isn't legal Java.  You can't have a loop and another loop nested inside it that have the same loop variable.

Comment: This is was just a sample Sysout. Is actually has a small logic written which I had replaced with Sysout. Its not even the String array, its our internal framework's object array that we are using in place of String array. Just tried to copy the similar logic. Sorry about the confusion. Just want to understand if there is a possibility to avoid these kind of nested loops.

Comment: @user2800970 Depends on what you are doing.  If you are doing searching you can use a binary search, but if you are doing something to a group of objects who have a list within them that holds the actual data to process, there doesn't seem to be a way around it.

Comment: @user2800970 Sometimes you need nested loops.  Sometimes you can make the code more readable by pulling out the inner loop(s) and putting them in a subroutine, but that won't improve performance.  The only thing we can do is to look at an algorithm and see if there's a more efficient way to do that particular algorithm; but there's no algorithm present in your code.